# Proving that a infinite sum of random variables converges

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales, bmo-martingales

Let $(X_n)_n$ be a sequence of independent random variables in a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ with $E(X_i) = \mu_i$ and $\text{var}(X_i) = \sigma^2_i$. Suppose that $\sum_n \mu_n <\infty$ and $\sum_n\sigma^2_n<\infty$. Then, I want to prove that
$$
\sum_{n\geq 1} X_i <\infty
$$
a.s.

What I am trying to do is to prove that $Y_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ is a supermartingale and applying Doob's theorem, but I can't since $\mu_i$ can either be positive or negative. Any hint? Thanks.

Comment: What about $Z_i=X_i-\mu_i$?

Comment: I thought it but if you put $E(Z_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n) = E(X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n) - \mu_{n+1} = E(X_{n+1}) - \mu_{n+1} = 0$, isn't it? And I do not know what to do with that...

Comment: Ah! I think I got you: $Z_n = \sum_{k=1}^n (X_k-\mu_k)$; then, $E(Z_{n+1}-Z_n|\mathcal{F}_n) = E(X_{n+1}-\mu_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n) = 0$, isn't it?

Comment: However, how do you prove the $L^1$-boundness to apply Doob's theorem? You have, $E|Z_n| \leq \sum_{k=1}^n E|X_k-\mu_k|$... I think only $L^2$ convergence is assured (since $\sum \sigma^2_k <\infty$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We consider $Y_{m}:=\sum_{n=1}^{m}(X_{n}-\mu_{n})$, note that $\left\{Y_{m}\right\}_{m\geq 1}$ is a martingale respect to $\mathcal{F}_{m}:=\sigma(X_{1},\ldots,X_{m})$. Indeed, we have that
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[Y_{m+1}|F_{m}]&=\mathbb{E}[Y_{m}+(X_{m+1}-\mu_{m+1})|\mathcal{F}_{m}]\\
&=\mathbb{E}[Y_{m}|\mathcal{F}_{m}]+\mathbb{E}[X_{m+1}|\mathcal{F}_{m}]-\mathbb{E}[\mu_{m+1}|\mathcal{F}_{m}]\\
&=Y_{m}+\mathbb{E_{m+1}}-\mu_{m+1}\\
&=Y_{m}+\mu_{m+1}-\mu_{m+1}\\
&=Y_{m}.
\end{align}

We also have that $\left\{Y_{m}\right\}_{m\geq 1}$ is bounded in $L^{2}$, to prove this fact we use the following result:

> Let $M=\left\{M_{n}\right\}_{n\geq 1}$ be a martingale, then $M$ is bounded in $L^{2}$ if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[(M_{n}-M_{n-1})^{2}]<\infty$.

In that sense, note that
\begin{align}
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[(Y_{m}-Y_{m-1})^{2}] &=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[(X_{m}-\mu_{m})^{2}] \\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sigma_{m}^{2} <\infty.
\end{align}
So, $\left\{Y_{m}\right\}_{m\geq 1}$ is bounded in $L^{2}$. But we know that bounded in $L^{2}$ implies uniformly integrable (UI), then  $\left\{Y_{m}\right\}_{m\geq 1}$ is uniformly integrable (UI). Therefore, $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}Y_{m}$ exists a.s, that is, $\sum_{n\geq 1} X_n <\infty$ a.s.

Comment: Oh, nice. I did not know yet that $L^2$ implies UI. I will check, thank you.

Comment: By the way, I tried this other thing to prove the $L^1$-boundness: using that $x\leq 1+x^2$ whenever $x\geq 0$. Hence, we wan write $E|Y_n|\leq 1 + E|Y_n|^2$. After a couple of calculations we would have an expression with the sum of the variances and thus it would be integrable. Do you like it?

Comment: @RubénFernándezFuertes It is known that bounded in $L^2$ implies bounded in $L^1$, your proposal would be showing this fact.

Comment: it's true; thank you!